# How to make multiple figures closer together?

Tags: graphics, fontsize, graphs

I have 12 plots which I want to make them one figure explaining the situation in the different scenarios. But when I try to put them together, they become far from each other.
[image]

which causes the number of the values to become really small. Even by increasing the font size, they are still too small. I think if I could make them closer I can make them bigger.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Are the 12 images contained in separate files? Please show us what you've tried so far. Please also indicate whether the copious whitespace that currently surrounds the graphs is part of the graphics files or if it's inserted during the process of creating 12-image `figure`.

Comment: Add `\fbox{...}` around `\includegraphics{}` (without any intervening white space). This will tell you how big the picture are. Moreover, provide a small complete document that shows the way how the images are combined to a single float.

Comment: @gernot thanks for the answer, Sorry I'm new in Latex, would you mind tell me how to use that?

Comment: Use `\fbox{\includegraphics[...]{...}}` instead of `\includegraphics`. It will draw a box around the image. The white space within the box comes from the image, the white space outside the way you typeset the collection of images. In the first case, you can either crop the image with a graphics editor or can crop it when loading the image (via options of `\includegraphics`). In the second case, one has to see how you typeset the figures to understand where the white space comes from, in order to do it differently.

Comment: To get a small document, copy everything from `\begin{figure}` to `\end{figure}` to a new file, replace the filenames of the images by `example-image` (it is part of standard distributions and should be found automatically), add the minimal number of lines from your preamble to make the document compilable by itself, verify that it still shows your problem, and add the code to your question (use the `edit` button left below the question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is an option for you:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{figure*}
        
        \begin{subfigure}{.2\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
            \caption{Label 1}\label{fig:Label1}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hspace*{\fill}
        \begin{subfigure}{.2\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
            \caption{Label 2}\label{fig:Label2}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hspace*{\fill}
        \begin{subfigure}{.2\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
            \caption{Label 3}\label{fig:Label3}
        \end{subfigure}
    
    
        \begin{subfigure}{.2\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
            \caption{Label 4}\label{fig:Label4}
        \end{subfigure}
            \hspace*{\fill}
        \begin{subfigure}{.2\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
            \caption{Label 5}\label{fig:Label5}
        \end{subfigure}
            \hspace*{\fill}
        \begin{subfigure}{.2\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
            \caption{Label 6}\label{fig:Label6}
        \end{subfigure}
    
        \begin{subfigure}{.2\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
            \caption{Label 7}\label{fig:Label7}
        \end{subfigure}
            \hspace*{\fill}
        \begin{subfigure}{.2\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
            \caption{Label 8}\label{fig:Label8}
        \end{subfigure}
            \hspace*{\fill}
        \begin{subfigure}{.2\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
            \caption{Label 9}\label{fig:Label9}
        \end{subfigure}
    
        \begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
            \caption{Label 10}\label{fig:Label10}
        \end{subfigure}
            \hspace*{\fill}
        \begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
            \caption{Label 11}\label{fig:Label11}
        \end{subfigure}
            \hspace*{\fill}
        \begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
            \caption{Label 12}\label{fig:Label12}
        \end{subfigure}
    
    \caption{\lipsum[1]}
    
    \end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do all the assembly using 'tabular'. The environment will keep the figures centered in their cells while maintaining their relative distances, if you increase the size of them.

The prototype includes a length `\figwidth` that allows you to test the behavior while resizing all the figures.

Looking at your example, I assumed that the figures in the last row are larger. If this is not the case, change all `1.3\figwidth` to `\figwidth`. The result will look much better and will allow for more resizing before reaching the margin.

[image: a]

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
    
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % dummy text    
\usepackage[left=1.2in, right=1.2in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}

\newlength{\figwidth}
\setlength{\figwidth}{1.4in}

\begin{document}                
    
\begin{figure*}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
        \includegraphics[height=\figwidth,width=\figwidth]{example-image-a}&
        \includegraphics[height=\figwidth,width=\figwidth]{example-image-a}&
        \includegraphics[height=\figwidth,width=\figwidth]{example-image-a} \\[6pt] %vertical space between the rows
        \includegraphics[height=\figwidth,width=\figwidth]{example-image-b}&
        \includegraphics[height=\figwidth,width=\figwidth]{example-image-b}&
        \includegraphics[height=\figwidth,width=\figwidth]{example-image-b} \\[6pt]
        \includegraphics[height=\figwidth,width=\figwidth]{example-image-c}&
        \includegraphics[height=\figwidth,width=\figwidth]{example-image-c}&
        \includegraphics[height=\figwidth,width=\figwidth]{example-image-c} \\[6pt]
        \includegraphics[height=1.3\figwidth,width=1.3\figwidth]{example-grid-100x100pt}&
        \includegraphics[height=1.3\figwidth,width=1.3\figwidth]{example-grid-100x100pt}&
        \includegraphics[height=1.3\figwidth,width=1.3\figwidth]{example-grid-100x100pt}    \\
    \end{tabular}
        \caption{Some images with tabular: height  1.4in.}
\end{figure*}

2. \kant[2] 
    
\end{document}
```

**Note.** I assumed that the your figures are properly trimmed, e.g. they do not have white space around. If this is not the case, they should be cropped before inserting into the LaTeX document.

Try inserting your images in the code above to see what happens.